# Зачем отнимают две сотые в медиа запросах

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста, зачем люди отнимают 2 сотые (0.02) от числа, в медиа запросах? То есть, вместо 768, пишут 767.98. Что это дает?

Comment: Возможно, они считают, что это у них такой пинг

Comment: Сам никогда так не делаю, но думаю из-за обратной сетки, например:
bootstrap использует min-width, если ты хочешь установить правило которое использует max-width и не пересекается с этим, нужно ставить меньше чем в min-width, а 0,02 наверное из-за округления. 
это мое мнение

Comment: Это обработка граничных значений. Обычно так поступают из-за неуверенности в поведении браузера. Например, при медиазапросе `@media screen and (max-width : 768px)` человек не знает, отработает ли он при ширине РОВНО в 768 пикселей (айпад в книжной ориентации), поэтому перестраховываются. Так же делают в случае, когда хотят в медиазапросе исключить четко 768 пикселей, но включить все, что меньше этого значения, с поправкой на то, что модные фреймворки могут считать в дробных пикселях, которые потом округляются, а ошибки округления могут накапливаться однонаправленно и портить результат.